# Read file with medium trust

Tags: c#, wcf, file-io, .net-4.5

I need to read a file into an byte array. I use File.ReadAllBytes (using System.IO).

> var txtbyte = File.ReadAllBytes("randomtext.txt");

It works for the localhost but in dedicated server I get an error:

> 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.'

My read and write permissions are OK for the virtual directory at the host. The host does not allow me to change trust level in config file. So I need to find another way to read the file.